# URL not fetching the data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to give a post request to the required URL but without proxy setting it was giving cors `error`, I have gone through and end up with setting the proxy but still it is taking the localhost as the URL. I have attached my `proxyfile.js` and my code snippet with the `error` below.

```
export function PostData(userData) {
  var targetUrl = "/downloadableReport";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(targetUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        requestData: {
          userName: userData.userName,
          password: userData.password
        }
      })
    }).then(response => response.json());
  });
}
```

This is the `setupProxy.js` code:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    proxy("/downloadableReport", {
      target: "http://192.168.1.220:28080/xms/abc",
      changeOrigin: true
    })
  );
};
```

And this is the error:

[image]

Comment: Did you try using the `proxy` option in `package.json` to avoid CORS? [Using React's Proxy to get ahead of CORS & use HTTPS for API calls](https://blog.praveen.science/using-reacts-proxy-to-get-ahead-of-cors/) - This is an article I wrote, which I explain it in detail. Let me know.

Comment: But again, you error seems like it's a `404 Not Found` error and not a CORS issue. Can you confirm this for me?

Comment: It works fine! but in the article its written it is for deployment server and not for production what it means by that. Also if you go through my code once ,I have in past used proxy in this way because i needed to have multiple hits on different url .How to achieve that? As my code with other project is working fine.But here it is not taking the proxy url

Comment: yes,As i told you it was working fine but it is not taking the proxy url, rather taking localhost so giving 404 error

Comment: Does `http://localhost:3000/downloadableReport` is valid `URL` ? looks like it is not a valid `URL` that's why causing `404(Not found)`. Check your server side code `URL`.

Comment: @AyushiKeshri I won't be able to go through your code as it's not available or not shared right? Anything that deals with proxy I could see is the setupProxy: `const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");`

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha , actually the right url it is expecting is http://192.168.1.220:28080/xmsreport/report/downloadableReport but getting localhost in place of ip address thus showing 404

Comment: @Praveen I understand the difficulty , though your documentation has helped me resolve my issue right now

Comment: @AyushiKeshri Woohoo! I am happy. Tell me what you did, I'll post it as an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If CORS is the problem and you are using express as the backend server,
then

```js
var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Role');
  // intercept OPTIONS method
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

and then add

```js
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Ditch the proxy. To me, your problem looks like, you're POSTing data to the React App itself. If you are indeed having both the API and React, in the same project, I would suggest that you split them.

If they are not indeed together, update the `targetUrl` to a proper url with the protocol and the domain. Like `var targetURl = 'http://localhost:3000/downloadableReport`.

**UPDATE**: I read your comment reply to Sudhir. Edit the target Url as the full path to the API `var targetUrl = "http://192.168.1.220:28080/xmsreport/report/downloadableReport"` and add the CORS code I have provided above to the API at 192.168.1.220:28080